# grep including tab in string and multiple searches

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to search for multiple things in a file using grep. I am trying to combine two grep lines together which is unsuccessful. To search for multiple strings I am doing the following:

```
grep 'a\|b\|c' file
```

To search for a string containing a tab I am using the following:

```
grep -P '1\ta' file
```

But to search for multiple strings all containing tabs combining the two does not work:

```
grep -P '1\ta\|2\tb\|3\tc' file
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Consider [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `grep -P $'1\ta\|2\tb\|3\tc' file`.  I note that your first command used `\|` — you may need to avoid those backslashes in the third (`grep -P $'1\ta|2\tb|3\tc' file`).  Also, the first command appears to be looking for an empty string after the third `\|`; that may not be what you intended.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you need to escape the `\ ` before the `|` so `grep` sees it.

Comment: @Kevin: Not really: `echo $'\|'` echoes a backslash and a pipe.  Actually, the backslash is not wanted with `-P`; it means look for a literal pipe symbol, not alternation (a metacharacter).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Please provide an input file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's interesting, `$'\|'` echoes the backslash in bash, but not zsh (which I was using to test). And note that OSX's `grep` doesn't have `-P`.

Comment: @Kevin: Isn't it fun — different shells behave differently.  That's interesting, and I wasn't aware of that difference between `bash` and `zsh` (nor am I aware of many others, no doubt).  I'm not wholly convinced the `bash` interpretation is sensible, but in C, the sequence `'\|'` (or `"\|"`) is invoking undefined behaviour, so anything is reasonable.  It sounds as though the `zsh` interpretation is `\z` for a `z` without a defined mapping maps to `z`; `bash` has chosen to interpret it as backslash followed by `z`.  They're neither wrong if you try to appeal to ANSI C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024196/grep-including-tab-in-string-and-multiple-searches#comment59699317_36024196) into an answer.*</sup>

Consider using Bash's [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
grep -P $'1\ta\|2\tb\|3\tc' file
```

I note that your first command used `\|` — you may need to avoid those backslashes in the third:

```
grep -P $'1\ta|2\tb|3\tc' file     # Recommended solution to immediate problem
```

Answer (score 3):

The extended regexp mode in grep should also work:

```
grep -E '1\ta\|2\tb\|3\tc' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use awk, as it understands extended regex syntax and escape sequences such as `\t` just fine:

```
awk '/1\ta|2\tb|3\tc/' file
```

It seems overkill to me to use features specific to bash (`$''`) or GNU grep (`-P`) in this case.

Here's another option you might like to consider:

```
grep -Ff patterns file
```

Where `patterns` is a file containing the fixed strings that you are trying to match, e.g.:

```
1   a
2   b
```

(with a literal tab characters in the file). The `-F` switch matches fixed strings.